# Partition full, file system not

Tags: 16.04, partitioning, mount, disk

I am running Ubuntu 16.04 in a VMWare VM.

My root partition `/dev/mapper/vg_ldt-lv_root` is almost full, which is mounted to `/`:

```
$ df -h
Filesystem                  Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev                        3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /dev
tmpfs                       797M   80M  718M  10% /run
/dev/mapper/vg_ldt-lv_root   33G   30G  1.9G  94% /
tmpfs                       3.9G   54M  3.9G   2% /dev/shm
tmpfs                       5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs                       3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda1                   1.9G  160M  1.6G  10% /boot
tmpfs                       797M     0  797M   0% /run/user/998
tmpfs                       797M   88K  797M   1% /run/user/3841712
tmpfs                       797M     0  797M   0% /run/user/999
```

So I tried investigating where the disk space went. I used `sudo ncdu` but it only returns me 14.2GB:

```
ncdu 1.11 ~ Use the arrow keys to navigate, press ? for help          
--- / ----------------------------------------------------------------
    6.1 GiB [##########] /usr                                         
    3.4 GiB [#####     ] /home
    2.0 GiB [###       ] /var
    1.2 GiB [##        ] /opt
  917.0 MiB [#         ] /lib
  372.7 MiB [          ] /root
  156.7 MiB [          ] /boot
.  79.4 MiB [          ] /run
   30.8 MiB [          ] /etc
   14.6 MiB [          ] /sbin
   12.8 MiB [          ] /bin
   12.4 MiB [          ] /tmp
  456.0 KiB [          ] /dev
e  16.0 KiB [          ] /lost+found
   12.0 KiB [          ] /emul
    8.0 KiB [          ] /isec
    8.0 KiB [          ] /McAfee
    8.0 KiB [          ] /mnt
    8.0 KiB [          ] /media
    4.0 KiB [          ] /lib64
e   4.0 KiB [          ] /srv
e   4.0 KiB [          ] /cdrom
e   4.0 KiB [          ] /Quarantine
.   0.0   B [          ] /proc
    0.0   B [          ] /sys
@   0.0   B [          ]  initrd.img.old
@   0.0   B [          ]  initrd.img
@   0.0   B [          ]  vmlinuz.old
@   0.0   B [          ]  vmlinuz
e   0.0   B [          ] /net


 Total disk usage:  14.2 GiB  Apparent size:  13.9 GiB  Items: 871532
```

How can I find out where the missing 15GB are?

Comment: I do not know LVM, but believe that is correct. The LVM - logical volume takes up all of the physical volume space. Actually I would expect it to be 100% full, or is part a logical volume swap? https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Lvm LVM is often used with server installs and is required with encrypted drive installs. But it is considered a more advanced partitioning system better used by those who know Linux well.

Comment: Actually, the space is shrinking when I delete files, it has been 99% before